# XML API Aviation Weather Center

Tags: ruby, xml

I am using ruby to collect METAR and TAF data from the Aviation Weather Center.

Their API is https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver

I am using rest client

My code looks like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'

url = 'https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=KMEM&hoursBeforeNow=1'

results=RestClient.get(url)
```

However after doing this in the command prompt I receive an long error msg, shown below.

Am I missing any significant code in the `RestClient.get`?

```
Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1414:in `block in transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1411:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1384:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:270:in `net_http_do_request'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:418:in `block in transmit'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient.rb:65:in `get'
        from (irb):67
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it works fine on my machine. It may just be a flaky, intermittent API endpoint? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39786260/1954610

Comment: Aweosme. It was something with my Network!